Why is make_unique<T[N]>() illegal while make_shared<T[N]>() is legal?
The proposal for shared_ptr<T[N]> has this paragraph:
https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3920.html

The unfortunate occurence of unique_ptr having lost its support for U[N] obliges me to assert that in shared_ptr case, said support is essentially free, both in terms of implementation complexity or specification complexity. Please don't remove it. Consider reinstating unique_ptr<U[N]> instead.

Is it simply a case of 'no-one has since proposed to restore unique_ptr<T[N]>', or is there some technical or backwards compatibility reason it can't be done?
I looked at these two existing questions:

Why is `make_unique<T[N]>` disallowed?
Why allow shared_ptr<T[N]>?

The first question was written pre-shared_ptr<T[N]>, and the second considers why shared_ptr<T[N]> was added but not why it wasn't also added to unique_ptr.

The basic dynamic allocation syntax for arrays is new T[n] which doesn't eventually support fixed size arrays: the size is managed through compiler magic in either case and released via delete[] ptr;. As a result, neither unique_ptr, nor shared_ptr are supposed to get a different type for fixed sized arrays. If you need fixed sized arrays use std::array. It has well-defined behavior and no runtime overhead for size calculations. As a legacy from C, raw arrays have always been bastards and treated that way.

I don't need fixed size arrays.  I was writing some generic code which should work with either shared_ptr or unique_ptr when I encountered this discrepancy and could not think of a good reason for the lack of genericity.

Good reason is the fundamental difference between C arrays and ordinary types. C arrays are reference types, which makes them different. This makes them difficult to deal with in any context. Best option is to ignore their existence; because workarounds are not any more expensive.

C arrays are not reference types. They are object types just like int. What you're probably thinking of is the ability to do array-to-pointer conversion, which turns them into pointers in some, but not all scenarios.

@JanSchultke they're effectively and semantically reference types. You cannot call a function to a value of C array type directly. The type will be replaced by a pointer to first element and the highest extent is removed. It is indeed reference semantics, but like everything else about C a bit twisted.

The primary reason behind introduction of memcpyas s library function is that C arrays cannot be assigned (another property of reference types) - otherwise, memcpy must be the compiler generated code for assignment operation. Compare the class keyword's implications in OOP languages (JAVA, C#). They are officially called reference types, because of similar properties.

std::make_unique<T[N]> is allowed, but almost certainly wrong because the deleter does the wrong thing in this scenario.
std::default_delete<T[N]> doesn't have a partial specialization for fixed-size arrays either, so it uses delete for an array type, and this would be undefined behavior.
In other words, std::unique_ptr<T[N]> is likely wrong, should have a custom deleter, but std::make_unique doesn't let you specify a deleter.
On top of that, it's also difficult to specify how std::make_unique works for arrays. Currently, [unique.ptr.create] specifies:

unique_ptr<T>(new T(std​::​forward<Args>(args)...))


However, this would not work for arrays because new T where T = U[N] yields U*, not U(*)[N].
For array types, this would need to be:
unique_ptr<U[N]>(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<U(*)[N]>(new U[N] {args...})));

However, this also wouldn't work in constant expressions because reinterpret_cast is not allowed there.
Even C++26's constexpr cast from void* doesn't get around this issue.
Overall, it should be clear that supporting std::unique_ptr<U[N]> and std::make_unique<U[N]> is not so trivial.
It is possible, but arrays are quite special in the C++ language and need lots of customization and special attention in various places within the standard library.
This special attention is a waste of everyone's time because you can just use std::unique_ptr<std::array<U, N>> instead.
C-style arrays are dumb.
Okay, but why is std::shared_ptr<T[N]> allowed?
std::shared_ptr is much easier to support.
std::shared_ptr uses type erasure, and doesn't involve std::default_delete.
We can just say that "delete[] will be used for array types" for the most part.
This type erasure and atomic reference counting also made it implausible for support in constant expressions to be provided back in C++17.
However, there is a proposal for C++26 now: P3037: constexpr std::shared_ptr

I don't see any difficulty.  std::default_delete<T[N]> is trivial to specialise, and std::make_unique<T[N]> can be defined as having the same implementation as the T[] overload, just with a compile-time N: unique_ptr<T>(new remove_extent_t<T>[N]()).  https://godbolt.org/z/oMqW74n3P

If smart pointers are allowed to be initialized from raw pointers, none of this helps much. Assume a smart_pointer to fixed sized array, initialized to a pointer of wrong element count. If the committee is about to fix anything, they should totally redesign C++ arrays; probably a distinct built-in type, with proper behavior.

@Fuz yes, as I've said, it's possible to accommodate raw arrays more, but it's a bit of a waste of time. You also have two competing styles for unique arrays if you add that support: std::unique_ptr<T[N]>(new T[N]) and std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[N]), and only one of these is essential. You also don't get access to the original T[N] object in constant expressions.

shared_ptr<T[N]> is no less redundant by that reasoning.  My query was concerning any technical reasons for the discrepancy because it happens to make my generic coding harder.  I wasn't looking for subjective opinion on whether one or the other is good/bad, easy/hard or useful/useless.
